# Top menu bar issue in magento

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, magento

I am new to magento, currently facing issue on finding js function.

[my top menu bar image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYhty.jpg)

in above menu when i click customer service link a popup message is displayed i want to customize its content.
so far i found top menu bar file, its located in `app/design/frontend/rwd/<theme>/template/page/html/top_menu_bar.php`

code,

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="customerservies();">CUSTOMER SERVICE</a>
```

my question is where this `customerservies()` function definition will be present? 
please help me to sort this issue..

Answer (score 0):

It's really difficult to answer this, because this functionality is not default Magento, but a custom one.

That being said, you should first search for the Javascript method in the template file that you've provided, between `<script>` tags.

If the method isn't there, you must search for it in the `www/skin/frontend/rwd/<theme>/js` or `www/js` directories.